# Changed static files are cropped/padded to the new size and served the old - Fedora

Tags: caching, webserver, fedora

I have a very strange problem. I have a Fedora 14 installed on a Virtualbox machine and I use it as a working copy server on my Windows 7 host.

It has a webserver installed (first Apache, then I changed to lighttpd to see if ot solves the problem) and I am editing files on a shared folder, and then load them in the W7 host via the webserver.

The weird thing is, that there is some kind of caching issue, because whenever I edit a static file, the older version is served, except that is is cropped to the size of the new file, of it the new file got bigger, it is padded with 0 bytes to have the size of the new.

I tried to change webservers, disable caching, everything, it just does not work (even in different browsers). When I open the files on the Linux server, they look all right.

Do you have any clue what this could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally turned out to be a known issue with the sendfile support of both Apache and Lighttpd.

It can be fixed with

```
EnableSendfile off
```

...on Apache and

```
server.network-backend = "writev"
```

...on Lighttpd.

Both worked.

Comment: I'm having pretty much the same problem, but not with Apache. I don't suppose you have any ideas? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460463/server-is-serving-old-versions-of-static-files-but-trimmed-or-padded-to-match-l#17460463