# Server is serving old versions of static files, but trimmed or padded to match length of new versions

Tags: caching, flask, gunicorn, werkzeug

The symptoms of my problem match this question pretty much exactly: [Changed static files are cropped/padded to the new size and served the old - Fedora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886606/changed-static-files-are-cropped-padded-to-the-new-size-and-served-the-old-fed)

Whenever I make changes to my static files (e.g. .js and .css), those changes don't show up in the served file. However, if my changes cause the file to change length, then the served file *does* match the new length:

- If I delete characters from anywhere in the static file, then the served file is trimmed at the end by that many characters.
- If I add characters to anywhere in the static file, then the served file is padded with that many � (that's U+FFFD) characters at the end.

The reason the linked answer doesn't solve my problem is that I'm not using Apache. I'm writing a Python web app for Heroku, so I'm using gunicorn and Flask (and therefore Werkzeug). The linked answer says that disabling sendfile in Apache solved the problem, so I tried setting the 'USE_X_SENDFILE' variable to False, as per [this page](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/), but it didn't help. I also set 'SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT' to 1 in a further attempt to prevent some sort of caching from happening, and that didn't help either.

If it's not obvious, I really don't know much at all about configuring web servers, so having run out relevant Google hits, I'm at a loss as to what might be causing this. Help?

Comment: it's a virtualbox `sendfile` issue. see also http://serverfault.com/questions/269420/disable-caching-when-serving-static-files-with-nginx-for-development and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886606/changed-static-files-are-cropped-padded-to-the-new-size-and-served-the-old-fed and http://abitwiser.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/virtualbox-hates-sendfile/

Comment: I see the same problem. It's not present when running the development server with Flask, only when using gunicorn. I'm using Vagrant to manage a VirtualBox VM. I'm not running nginx or Apache, not sure if there's an option for disabling sendfile in gunicorn (if it's even an option).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Virtualbox hates sendfile.](https://abitwiser.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/virtualbox-hates-sendfile/) If you turn it off it should work.

For example in nginx you would need to add `sendfile: off;`.
In Apache it's just `EnableSendfile off`.

Comment: You have stopped me from ageing 10 more years overnight!

Answer (score 2):

In the end it turned out that this was probably being caused by VM issues. The code in question was located on a Windows drive, but was being served from within a Linux VM that was accessing the code via a shared directory. Remounting the share seemed to fix the problem (although not necessarily reliably).

Comment: I have the same issue. A vagrant VM runs an nginx server which servers a static file which is located on the host. When the file changes, the trim/pad as you desribe it happens. Do you know of an easy fix without remounting the share?

Comment: fixed it by adding `sendfile: off;` to my nginx configuration because [virtualbox hates sendfile](http://abitwiser.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/virtualbox-hates-sendfile/)

Comment: @Alp: Could you post this as an answer? I had the exact same problem and this solved it.

Comment: @graup: Glad it helped you. I posted an answer as you requested :)