# <script> only loads half the time -- "Loading failed for the <script> with source", and only works when Firefox sends a range in the request

Tags: javascript, html, http, firefox, flask

First off, apologies as I'm not experienced with StackOverflow. I also am clueless as to what the problem is.

I'm running a Flask server, and all other scripts have worked fine up to this point. However, when I attempt to load pdf.js in the same way, it only loads some of the time. Other times, it give this error in the Firefox console: 
`Loading failed for the <script> with source`
However, I noticed that when it *does* work, it always sends a Range in the header.

I've tried loading it from another source, which worked fine. I've tried several different type in the `<script>` tag, from `text/javascript` to `application/javascript` to just blank. I've also tried changing how it's loaded in the JINJA2 template.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js">
</script>
```

Any ideas on what this is? Thank you!

EDIT: 
Working Network Tab

[image: Working Network Tab]

Working Request

[image: Working Request]

Non-Working Request

[image: Non-Working Request]

Non-Working Network Tab

[image: Non-Working Network Tab]

Comment: Could you please add some screenshots from your browser's _Network_ console? What do the headers, request body and response look like for both working and not-working requests?

Comment: How are you running the server? If you're using a VM, see [Server is serving old versions of static files, but trimmed or padded to match length of new versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460463/server-is-serving-old-versions-of-static-files-but-trimmed-or-padded-to-match-l)

Comment: @Phil I added screenshots of the tabs. Apologies for the late reply, I didn't get the notification email.