# Nginx and Gunicorn with Virtualbox serves old verison of Django static files padded/cropped to new file size, sendfile off doesn't work

Tags: nginx, vagrant, virtualbox, gunicorn, sendfile

My problem is the same one as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460463/server-is-serving-old-versions-of-static-files-but-trimmed-or-padded-to-match-l) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886606/changed-static-files-are-cropped-padded-to-the-new-size-and-served-the-old-fed), but with the exception that setting `sendfile off;` in **nginx.conf** does not help.

I'm running Vagrant with Virtualbox (Ubuntu 16.04) and Nginx, Gunicorn, and Django. I use this setup for development, so I want to avoid having to call `collectstatic` every time a file is changed. As such, Nginx routes all requests to Gunicorn (even '/static/'), and Gunicorn serves the static files using this approach:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

This works, with the exception that if I change something in a static file, the contents are not updated, only the file size. I have tried setting `sendfile off;` in **nginx.conf**, and also in my Gunicorn configuration. Still, the problem remains. Is there any way I could try to narrow down the possible cause of this issue?

All Django files are in folder that is shared with the Windows 10 host system, but if I use `vagrant ssh` and check out the files, they have updated properly.

**Edit:** The problem persists if I run Gunicorn only without Nginx, so it seems to be a Gunicorn/Django problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I needed to run Gunicorn with the `--no-sendfile` flag as well. I tried setting it in my ini-file before (`no_sendfile = True`), which did not work. However, adding `--no-sendfile` to my Gunicorn run command in supervisor worked!